# How to add IEDriverServer to PATH

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, cucumber, selenium-webdriver

I am elaborating on a question I asked yesterday about PATHs. I am trying to run my selenium tests in IE 8. I have downloaded the IEDriverServer_x64_2.33.0 and it is located in my downloads folder. I have tried adding this location in the following ways:

Control Panel> System>Advanced> Environment Variables

[image: Inserted in ClassPath]
[image: Inserted in PATH]
[image: Created a new variable]

The path is separated by a semicolon in PATH and CLASSPATH (ex.;C:\Users\username\Downloads\IEDriverServer_x64_2.33.0) Neither of these gets my test to run. Could it be how i'm associating the ie browser? I can not run the driver in cmd.exe so i have assumed it is not this.

env.rb :

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rubygems'
require 'rspec/expectations'



@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie
```

Any advice. I hope this is enough information to show my problem.

Also here is the error output:

```
Unable to find standalone executable. Please download the IEDriverServer from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list and place the executable on your PATH. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **`unzip`** the IEdriver zip file first. Then provide `C:\Users\megaxelize\Downloads` in the path. Path to the IEDriver file is the path of the "folder" in which the IEDriver lies.

**UPDATE**

For a quick test, just drop the IEDriver (not the zip file) and drop it in `C:\Windows\System32. Then run your tests.

Comment: I should have mentioned I have tried this already. I was last copying the procedure of someone who did not unzip it. I did attempt this again, following the same format I have images of but this time unzipping the file and giving the path to the folder the .exe lies in. Same error though. Maybe it takes time for the Path to update? I just ran PATH in cmd and I can now see the path to the zip  file. This was not the case directly after I made the changes.

Comment: Made an update, note you dont need to provide the file name in the path, just the folder in which the IEDriver lives. Also the PATH is updated instantly so there should not be any delay.

Comment: Progress! I am able to run it from the cmd but I am still getting the same error when I run my test cases. Also the correct path is specified when I run PATH now. Could you elaborate on this anymore?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. What can you run from the cmd Vs something else?

Comment: The Path is updated by dropping the IEDriver into System32? Just clarifying.

Comment: okay, so once you drop the IEDriver in System32, close your cmd prompt and reopen it. Then run your tests again.

Comment: I am able to run the IEDriver. I was just saying this is an improvement. But Selenium doesn't seem to be picking up on this as I am still getting the same error output.

Comment: How are you `running` the IEDriver? what does that mean?

Comment: Closing and reopening the cmd (and i'm using cygwin i restarted that as well)did the trick.The IE browser has opened successfully and the error is gone. Thank you for the information and patience!

Comment: I meant that when I typed IEDriverServer into the cmd it ran the executable. It just outputs:

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\mewalsh>IEDriverServer
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.33.0.0
Listening on port 5555

I was referring to this happening. Apologies for being confusing, I'm learning how to describe my problems.

Comment: Great! So just for reference, any update to an environment/path requires a cmd prompt restart. Also if this answer helped you please, mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Unzip** the IEDriver.zip file in any folder, so that folder contains IEDriver file
e.g 
you unzipped it in **C:\Drivers\**

- Copy path till that folder. means only **C:\Drivers\**
- Go to My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced Settings -> Environment Variables
- Under that in front of PATH paste our path i.e **C:\Drivers\** at the end and before that put **;**
- Apply the changes made
- Restart command prompt